# Do Particle Filters actually approximate the posterior distribution?

Tags: probability, distributions, monte-carlo, importance-sampling, particle-filter

Im reading a tutorial paper about particle filters ([Link](https://ieeexplore.ieee.org/document/978374)) in which it is stated that as the number of samples tends to infinity the approximated posterior density given by

$p(x_k|z_{1:k}) \approx \sum_{i=1}^N w_k^i \delta(x_k - x^i_k)$

approaches the true posterior $p(x_k|z_{1:k})$. This is asserted without proof. As far as I understand, particle filters use Importance sampling to preserve statistics like $\mathbb{E}[f(x)]$. For example, the mean can be recovered by computing a weighted mean of the particles. However, Importance sampling doesn't guarantee that the new sample will approach the target distribution in the limit since it uses a different proposal distribution to sample from and reweights the samples. My question is then, how can the particle sample approximate the true posterior in the limit if the particles were sampled from a different distribution?